# My Mutsibish Pajero, Model 1995 has become hard to start in cold weather to start immediately

Tags: ignition, mitsubishi, pajero

My Mutsibish Pajero, Model 1995 has become hard to start in cold weather to start immediately.

I have to try like 2-3 times yet I do the pre-heating as required.

Comment: Hi Mugisha: what fuel does this motor use? Diesel or petrol?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!